# get a php variable in java script function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have this dropdown list  and i need to save it's value by javascript but i can't get the name of the php variable (select name ) into the function

drop down list :

```
   $i=0;
   while($i<$counter)
        {
      $vname=$row['student_id'].'_'.$i;
        echo"
          <td>

            <select name=".$vname.">
  <option value="."0".">Choose one</option>
 <option value="."1".">Add</option>
 <option value="."2".">R</option>
 <option value="."3".">TBR</option>
 <option value="."4".">P</option>
      </select>
   </td>";
       $i++;
            }
```

java script function :

```
           <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>                               
                     <script>
                 $(document).ready(function() {

             var item = window.localStorage.getItem('".$vname."');
              $('select[name=".$vname."]').val(item);

           $('select[name=".$vname."]').change(function() {
                 window.localStorage.setItem('".$vname."', $(this).val());
                 });

               });  
            </script>
```

Comment: We need to see the PHP code behind the Javascript code.

Comment: Also the select name is not between quotes

Comment: Nor are the option values.

Comment: I recommend `CTRL+A` and then `DELETE`. Do it all over again after reading some tutorials.

Comment: Also go and read up about proper use of string concatenation – `<option value="."0".">` doesn’t do what you probably think it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: `var vname = "<?php echo $vname; ?>";`

Then replace `$vname` with `vname` in your javascript functions.